# How to render objects in array in frontend table using ejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js, ejs

I am making a user management system where the admin can login and add user details into an array called data and render it in the form of a table.There is a front-end form for the same purpose.

The problem is, I am able to take information from the the front-end from and push it to the array but not able to render in that table.

This is my user schema:

```
    const userSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String,
    data: [{
        name: String,
        emailAdd: String,
        phone: Number,
    }] 
});
```

This is the post route for receiving user info and storing it in the array.

```
app.post("/add_user",function(req,res){
const userId=req.body.id;
    User.findOne({userId}, function(err, foundUser) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if (foundUser) {
                foundUser.data.push({
                    name:req.body.fname,
                    emailAdd:req.body.emailadd,
                    phone:req.body.phone
                  });
                foundUser.save(function() {
                    res.redirect("/database");
                });
                // console.log(foundUser);
            }
        }
    });
   
})
```

This is the get route for passing the object to front end:

```
app.get("/database", function(req, res) {
const userId=req.body.id;
if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    User.find({ _id:userId,"data": {$ne: null}}, function(err, foundUser) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("database", { newUser: foundUser });
        }
    });

    }else{
    res.redirect("/");
}
```

});

There is a  database.ejs page containing the table where I need to render it:

```
<table class="list" id="employeeList">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Full Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Number</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <%newUser.forEach(function(user){ %>   
        <tr>
          <td><%=user.data.name%></td>
          <td><%=user.data.emailAdd%></td>
          <td><%=user.data.phone%></td>
        </tr>
        <% }); %>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

The table still remains empty even after adding the user.
(P.S: I am using passport for encryption and mongoDB as database)
.No errors are showing up hence I don't know where I am going wrong.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you confirm if users are there in your db and column 'data' is not null?

Comment: When I console log the foundUser in /add_user route, the users and their info is visible.While when I console log the foundUser in /database route , it shows null.

Comment: If foundUser is null, then it won't render anything in table right. Kindly check if removing "data": {$ne: null}} condition from the find query helps or not. It might not be satisying the query and hence it would be returning null.